# Почему рейтинг по одной метке имеет разные значения?

Tags: поддержка, метки

Есть расхождение в рейтинге по метке на странице пользователя и в топе метки. Возьмем, например, меня и [git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git).

На [странице пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin?tab=topactivity) показывается 158 баллов:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в [топе по метке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git/topusers) — 186:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда разница? Как считаются оба рейтинга?

- Предположил сначала, что дело в общих ответах. Однако, у меня всего [один общий ответ с рейтингом 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A181472%20[git]%20wiki%3Ayes%20is%3Aanswer).
- Это точно не лаг в обновлении данных (если только лаг на 2-4 недели)
- Рейтинг за ответы на собственные вопросы сейчас (5 + 3 + 3 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 23 + 12) = 59. Тоже не то.

Comment: Кстати, а на мете только по метке `discussion` можно аналогичные показатели отслеживать? А то я хотел отслеживать свой прогресс по метке `нытьё`, но ничего кроме `discussion` не нашёл...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: а вот это интересный вопрос.

Comment: Во-во) А по теме вопроса - там внизу, вроде, приписка, что считается статистика раз в день. М.б. лаг?

Comment: Хм... Я тоже постоянно ловлю себя на мысли, что меня в рейтингах понижают... =)

Comment: вот [тут говорят](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306113/4827341), что проблема — в кэшировании. и можно обновить данные, щёлкнув по «шестерёнке» и выбрав ту же метку из списка.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: спасибо, помогло! Может, краткий ответ опубликуете?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

как пишут в ответах на [этот вопрос на английской *мете*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306113/4827341), проблема в кэшировании.

исправить можно, нажав «зубчатое колёсико» рядом с отслеживаемым знаком и вновь выбрав из открывшегося списка тот же самый знак.

Comment: Я переключал метки несколько раз - ничего не меняется. по `javascript` в кабинете указана как лучшая у меня, рейтинг больше 400. А в списке меток рейтинг так и не дошел до 100...

Comment: посмотрел, что у меня с меткой javascript. аналогичные показатели — 14 баллов — как в [личной сводке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpALb.png), так и в [общем рейтинге по метке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFxz1.png). может, вы не в тот список смотрите в [общем рейтинге](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers)? там ведь четыре таблицы — отдельно по вопросам и ответам, и отдельно за весь период и за последние тридцать дней.